# GTFS - route waits for another

Tags: gtfs

Is there a way how to express in GTFS, that one route is connected with another, that means, that the bus from the second route is waiting some time until the bus from the first route arrives?

**Example:**

Regular arrival of bus 1 (route 001) to the stop S1 is 12:00.

Regular departure of bus 2 (route 002) from the stop S1 is 12:05.

I would like to express in GTFS, that bus 2 will wait until 12:15, if the bus 1 is delayed

There is used file transfers.txt in [doc](https://developers.google.com/transit/gtfs/reference#transferstxt), but it does not seem that this is solving my problem. I would like have this just for some route pairs, not general for stop pairs.

Comment: Very interesting use case!

Answer (score 1):

You could express something like this in the stop name. You could do that only if it applies to all trips that stop there.

Expressing service intricacies like this is not uncommon.

An airport shuttle with fixed routes and times includes "24 hour advance reservations required" in its operator name. See the [Transitland blog post](https://transit.land/news/2016/10/03/truckee-transit.html) I wrote for details.

Answer (score 0):

No, GTFS provides no such mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old so you probably already figured this out, but I'll add my two cents anyway...

If two `Trip_ID`'s have the same `Block_Id`, that implies that the trips are being made by the same vehicle (or a replacement of the original vehicle) therefore **forcing the trip to "wait"**.

Directions via Google Maps already make use of this functionality by advising the passenger to stay on the current vehicle.

**From Google Maps / Directions :**

[image: Block_ID example]

Comment: This does not answer the question. The question is asking about timed transfers between two different vehicles on two different routes, not a single vehicle which is covering trips on multiple routes.